# Page TSconfig with conditions in FE

Tags: typo3

I'm using TYPO3 v7.6, and trying to overwrite some Page TSconfig with conditions and get it in FE.

What I did is,

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPageTSConfig('<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:EXT:'.$_EXTKEY.'/Configuration/PageTSconfig/pageTSConfig.txt">');`
```

in `ext_localconf.php` in my extension.

In the `pageTSConfig.txt`

```
RTE.tinymce {
    menu = 0
    menubar = 0
    plugins = code link lists
    statusbar = 0
    toolbar {
        0 = bold italic | alignleft aligncenter | bullist numlist | undo redo | formatselect | link unlink | code
    }
}
[PIDinRootline = 26]
    RTE.tinymce {
        plugins = code link lists textcolor colorpicker
        toolbar {
            0 = bold italic | forecolor | alignleft aligncenter | bullist numlist | undo redo | formatselect | link unlink | code
        }
    }
[end]
```

The condition works in Page TSconfig in BE. However, `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->pagesTSconfig()` in FE only gets the default `RTE.tinymce`, not the overwritten one in page `uid=26`. Did I miss anything?

BTW, I tried moving the condition part into the `Page TSConfig` box in page `uid=26`, and I can get the TSconfig correct with `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->pagesTSconfig()` in my extension.

Answer (score 0):

A possible way, but may not be a good way.

First, move the condition TSconfig into another file and loaded with

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPageTSConfig('<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:EXT:'.$_EXTKEY.'/Configuration/PageTSconfig/pageTSConfig2.txt" condition="[PIDinRootline = 26]">');`
```

See the feature at https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/7.5/Feature-16525-AddConditionsToINCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT.html

Then update `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\TypoScript\Parser\TypoScriptParser->checkIncludeLines()`

```
/** @var AbstractConditionMatcher $conditionMatcher */
$conditionMatcher = null;
if (TYPO3_REQUESTTYPE & TYPO3_REQUESTTYPE_FE) {
    $conditionMatcher = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(FrontendConditionMatcher::class);
} else {
    $conditionMatcher = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(BackendConditionMatcher::class);
}
// Make sure we can set the rootLine and pageId
if ($GLOBALS['TSFE']) {
    $conditionMatcher->setRootLine($GLOBALS['TSFE']->rootLine);
}
```

So, `[PIDinRootline = 26]` would work as expected, and the TSconfig will be loaded accordingly.

The reason for `if` is, when `$conditionMatcher` is initialized, no `rootLine` is set, and `->match()` will fail because `[treeLevel]`, `[PIDupinRootline]` and `[PIDinRootline]` requires it to work.